# V8 linker errors when building project on Ubuntu (c++)

Tags: c++, ubuntu, linker, v8, libc++

I have been trying to build V8 and link even the simplest project to it in c++ but I keep getting mass linker errors regarding libc++ but i'm unsure how to resolve it.  (most of my c++ experience is on windows but I'm building this on ubuntu, i've tried 16.04 and 18.04)

There are too many errors to post all of them here but it appears they all have to do with std::__1::{something}.  Here is an example:

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x53): undefined reference to v8::platform::NewDefaultPlatform(int, v8::platform::IdleTaskSupport, v8::platform::InProcessStackDumping, std::unique_ptr<v8::TracingController, std::default_delete<v8::TracingController> >)'
./v8/out.gn/x64.release/obj//libv8_monolith.a(api.o): In function `v8::SnapshotCreator::CreateBlob(v8::SnapshotCreator::FunctionCodeHandling)':
api.cc:(.text._ZN2v815SnapshotCreator10CreateBlobENS0_20FunctionCodeHandlingE+0x10e7): undefined reference to `std::__1::__vector_base_common<true>::__throw_length_error() const'
api.cc:(.text._ZN2v815SnapshotCreator10CreateBlobENS0_20FunctionCodeHandlingE+0x10f3): undefined reference to `std::__1::__vector_base_common<true>::__throw_length_error() const'
```

The contents of main.cpp:

```
#include <v8.h>
#include <libplatform/libplatform.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        v8::V8::InitializeICU();
        std::unique_ptr<v8::Platform> platform = v8::platform::NewDefaultPlatform();

        return 0;
}
```

The command I used to build it:

```
g++ -I. -I./v8/include main.cpp -o testv8 -lv8_monolith -L./v8/out.gn/x64.release/obj/ -pthread -std=c++0x
```

This is the doc I used to build V8 and used as reference for the command:
https://v8.dev/docs/embed

Let me know if any more info is required, thanks in advance!

EDIT:
All the tutorials and example code contains "#include <libplatform/libplatform.h>" and the ubuntu package seems to be missing it.
This is all the files in the Ubuntu V8 packages:

```
$ apt list --installed | grep v8
libv8-3.14.5/bionic,now 3.14.5.8-11ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libv8-dev/bionic,now 3.14.5.8-11ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]

$ dpkg -L libv8-3.14.5
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/libv8.so.3.14.5
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libv8-3.14.5
/usr/share/doc/libv8-3.14.5/AUTHORS
/usr/share/doc/libv8-3.14.5/README.Debian.security
/usr/share/doc/libv8-3.14.5/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libv8-3.14.5/copyright

$ dpkg -L libv8-dev
/.
/usr
/usr/include
/usr/include/v8-debug.h
/usr/include/v8-preparser.h
/usr/include/v8-profiler.h
/usr/include/v8-testing.h
/usr/include/v8.h
/usr/include/v8stdint.h
/usr/lib
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libv8-dev
/usr/share/doc/libv8-dev/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libv8-dev/examples
/usr/share/doc/libv8-dev/examples/count-hosts.js
/usr/share/doc/libv8-dev/examples/lineprocessor.cc.gz
/usr/share/doc/libv8-dev/examples/process.cc.gz
/usr/share/doc/libv8-dev/examples/samples.gyp
/usr/share/doc/libv8-dev/examples/shell.cc.gz
/usr/lib/libv8.so
/usr/share/doc/libv8-dev/AUTHORS
/usr/share/doc/libv8-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
```

SOLUTION:
installing libc++-dev and clang ubuntu packages and using this line to compile made everything work:

```
clang++ -I. -I./v8/include main.cpp -o testv8 -lv8_monolith -L./v8/out.gn/x64.release/obj/ -pthread -std=c++0x -stdlib=libc++
```

Comment: Why are you building v8 yourself? You should install the development package from your package manager.

Comment: Are you trying to build against a libc++ version from today? Because that may be my fault... If you update your libc++ version, the error should go away.

Comment: @n.m. I tried installing it but it appeared to be missing the libplatform.h and only contained libv8.so which I'm not sure how to use without the .a file (new to linux c++).  If you know how to do this approach though I'd totally be willing to switch.

Comment: @EricWF V8 has a lot of automation in setting up it's dependencies so i'm not really sure if it pulled a version from today.  It would seem a bit reckless of them to not use a stable version though :)

Comment: Oh, Are you passing `-stdlib=libc++`?

Comment: @EricWF I think that is a clang (osx?) specific flag.  I just installed clang++ for ubuntu and added it though but then it complains it can't find the memory include file? (#include <memory>)

Comment: Symbols starting with `std::__1::` belong to libc++. I think V8 is building against libc++ instead of the system default GNU libstdc++. So when you want to use it, you need to pass `-stdlib=libc++` as well.

Comment: You need to install the **dev** package. Not libv8. libv8-dev.

Comment: And don't let yourself be dragged into yet another [xy problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). If installing a package didn't quite work for you, *ask about that problem first*.

Comment: @n.m. I added some details about the packages I installed but most info i've found is building against v8 on windows or osx which isn't much help.  The official v8 getting started docs only mention building it so I thought it was the only real option.

Comment: You also need to instal nodejs-dev it seems. libplatform.h belongs to it.

Comment: Fixed it!  I needed to add the -stdlib=libc++ and use clang++ like @EricWF mentioned but the error I got about the missing headers was because I was missing the libc++-dev package.  Thank you both for your help!

Comment: @n.m. I'll give that method a shot too, building V8 takes a long time and it would be nice to not have to do that to get things working.